# How to insert an index for each row in existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a column named 'index' in my existing SQL table, `my_table`.

How to do it?

Original my_table:

```
name    sex age
Ben M   23
May F   20
Sam M   22
```

Desired my_table:

```
name    sex age id
Ben M   23  1
May F   20  2
Sam M   22  3
```

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What will the column contain? For example for mySQL, you can do this:http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/. Be careful this may affect existing code using this table, if any.

Comment: `index` is a reserved key word in SQL (the query language). Keywords have to be quoted in order to be usable as an identifier, e.g. `"index"` - but I highly recommend to find a different name. Using reserved keywords as column names will give you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2017 Express.

Comment: In the first row, the new column contains 1, the second row, we have 2, etc

Comment: The column name can be changed to `idx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX is a resrve word so it is not best practice to use that to create index but you use that in naming below way

```
create table mytable( id int,name varchar(100) );



    ALTER TABLE [mytable] DROP COLUMN ID 
    ALTER TABLE [mytable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Comment: I want to add the id column in existing table but not creating a new one

Comment: @John that means in your table does not have id column right now you want add that column in your table

Comment: I followed your command but I got NULL values in each row. I just want to add an index value for each row. In other words, the first row, we have 1, the second row, we have 2, etc.

Comment: @John https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6cf3a6923ad54469e1dacb8fc87276f check this fiddle does you need this

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create like that:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.my_table
ADD [index] INT
```

However, as said @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin, it is not best practice.

If you want to create an identification column then just use the following code to create unique column for each row:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.my_table
    ADD ID INT IDENTITY
    CONSTRAINT PK_my_table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name    Age     ID
Ben M   23      1
May F   20      2
Sam M   22      3
```